# Epp Ficora - Connection refused

Tags: php, epp

I have problem connecting to epp server : epptest.ficora.fi 
I'm using this PHP lib : https://packagist.org/packages/metaregistrar/php-epp-client

```
    $conn = new eppConnection(false);
    $conn->setHostname('epptest.ficora.fi');
    $conn->setPort(700);

    $realPath = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../../../data/keys/ficora.pem');
    if (!$realPath) {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
    $conn->enableCertification($realPath, 'passphrase');
    $conn->connect();
    return $conn->login();
```

Response : "Error connecting to ssl://epptest.ficora.fi:700: Connection refused (code 111)"

Already added my ip addresses . The port is 700
I generate certificate using : http://grahamc.com/blog/openssl-madness-how-to-create-keys-certificate-signing-requests-authorities-and-pem-files/

At epptest ui I upload the.crt file 
Any ideas , anyone with experience with FICORA ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at closed Ficora port 700 
nmap epptest.ficora.fi